# NodeJS multiple MySQL queries using result of one query for the next

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have been trying to achieve this for some time, and it's not been working. I had to go with a temporary solution of sql join statement (which, as you can imagine, isn't working as expected)

I am required to perform multiple mysql queries, and most of the time, I will need the result from one query for another. For example:

`let sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    con.query(sql,(err,users)=>{
     let anothersql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE uuid="+users.uuid+"; 
     con.query(anothersql,(err,posts)=>{ callback(200,{'posts',posts,'users'=>users}) })})`

This actually worked when I have just one user, but I need to perform this action on all users in the database, hence I need to fetch all users with their associated posts then return then all in that same order, i.e. result 1 => `{'users1':users,'post1':posts},{'users2':users,'post2':posts}`

I know there are ways to achieve this using promise, async etc, but I don't know how to do it. If anyone can point me in the direction of a tutorial or sample code, that would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

If you stumble on this question, don't do it manually, use Sequelize. Seriously, use Sequelize.

Comment: Well, the join is simple: `SELECT u.*, p.* FROM users u INNER JOIN posts p ON u.uuid = p.uuid`, so you could do that. Is that what you're looking for, or do you really want to loop over records and run loads of SQL queries in succession? Obv that's not as performant, but for learning's sake, you'd probably want to start by checking out [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (and really the intro promise documentation there on MDN).

Comment: Yes, I used join statement, but for the other aspect of the application, I'll really like a better way to achieve it. Maybe write a wrapper class for database or something

Comment: Well that's quite a different question :) Check out [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize). There are many others, I just recommend and use it. Checking out Promises and async / await will let you write clean, easy to read code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.